# Does PouchDB really keep all document revisions forever?

Tags: pouchdb

Something caught my eye on the PouchDB documentation from https://pouchdb.com/guides/compact-and-destroy.html:

> By default, PouchDB and CouchDB are designed to store all document
>   revisions forever.

This behavior is truly not ideal in my case, with a lot of document editing, the database would grow huge over time. So I decided to test it with couchdb's own task demo "getting started" app available on https://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html.

My test is: create tasks, edit them multiple times and then inspect them in the database with the PouchDB Inspector chrome extension. To my surprise, it seems that only the last revision is being saved on the database. If I'm not missing something and that is true, then why did they write "By default, PouchDB and CouchDB are designed to store all document revisions forever." on their official documentation? Am I missing something?

Comment: ok, apparently it's a problem (or maybe defauld behaviour?) in PouchDB Inspector, it does not show the older revisions, looking into indexedDB I was able to see that, yes, it is creating multiple revisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read just a few sentences more, you will see:

> To mitigate this problem, PouchDB offers two recourses: compaction and destruction.

And the rest of that page explains how to deal with it.

> To my surprise, it seems that only the last revision is being saved... Am I missing something?

I'm not familiar with the Chrome extension, but by default PouchDB will only show you the most recent revision unless you explicitly request others.

Further, by default, PouchDB keeps up to 1000 revisions of each document ([configurable with `revs_limit`](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_database)).  This is necessary to allow for conflict resolution when syncing with CouchDB.

If you never sync, or you know that you'll never need more than N revisions to resolve a conflict, you can set this to a lower number to save space.